# Reasons why my solution is not efficient (Largest Palindrome Substring, Leet Code)

Tags: java, optimization

I am solving this problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/) and my solution works (I am using sliding window technique) however it is just not efficient enough to pass longer input values. I was wondering if someone could explain why (at least this version) of sliding window is not efficient enough.
I have seen the answers that solve it fast enough but this is more of a question as to why this doesn't work

I have tried adding early exit cases, I have tried getting rid of unnecessary overhead of variables, however it is still not enough.

```
public String longestPalindrome(String s) {
    /*Use sliding window technique*/

    //Since we are finding the longest palindrome, start windowSize at the length of the string - 1
    int windowSize = s.length() - 1;

    //Loops through string
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        //Basically if i + windowSize goes over length, reset i to check slidingWindow at index 0 and decrement windowSize
        if (i + windowSize >= s.length()) {
            i = 0;
            windowSize -= 1;
        }

        //This is the window substring we are checking
        String window = s.substring(i, windowSize + i + 1);

        //This is an early exit statement
        if (isPalindrome(window)) { return window; }

        if (windowSize == 0) break;
    }
    return null;
}

private Boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    return new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString().equals(s);
}
```

Comment: See [_Longest palindromic substring_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring) for an _O(n)_ algorithm.

Comment: Creating and garbage-collecting many objects takes time.  For large strings, you will be creating a lot of StringBuffer objects, and a lot of additional String objects by calling `substring` and by calling StringBuffer’s `toString`.  Pass start and end indices to isPalindrome, and use String’s `charAt` method to do the check yourself instead of relying on StringBuffer.reverse.

Comment: @VGR seems widely unknown, [`append` with range](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence,int,int)) eliminates the need for `substring` and [`contentEquals(java.lang.CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#contentEquals(java.lang.CharSequence)) eliminates the need for `toString().equals(…)` when comparing a `String` with a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`. So a lot of object creation/string copying can be avoided, still, the time complexity doesn’t change.